# BLE trying to handle custom profile, getting Error receiving broadcast Intent

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

So i have a BLE peripheral with a custom UUID, and i'm able to connect to it fine. I can read the custom characteristic using:

```
 if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        int flag = characteristic.getProperties();
        int format = -1;
        if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
            Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT16.");
        } else {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
            Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT8.");
        }
        final int heartRate = characteristic.getIntValue(format, 1);
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Received heart rate: %d", heartRate));
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, String.valueOf(heartRate));
    }
    else {
        if(characteristic.getValue()!=null){
            final int data2 = characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT32, 0);

            intent.putExtra("Right",String.valueOf(data2));}
    }
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

But if i want to specify what to do with a specific characteristic:

```
public final static UUID chara = UUID.fromString("custom 128bit UUID");

private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                             final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    if(chara.equals(characteristic.getUuid())){
        if(characteristic.getValue()!=null){
            final int data2 = characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT32, 0);
   intent.putExtra("Right",String.valueOf(data2));}
    }
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

I get Error receiving broadcast Intent .....Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"

Can anyone please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

getIntValue returns Integer type and it may be null, will you have a try/exception for that line. 
and, shouldn't be you successfully get the data2 then sendBroadcast but does not always send the broadcast?